# Second wifi router for internal LAN file transfer - freeing up main internet wifi signal

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dropbox, wifi-configuration, wifi-transfer

We use Dropbox to share large files (100mb) which need to be kept in sync on multiple machines, this is fine, but slows down the network with it constantly uploading and downloading these files.

Is it possible to setup a second wifi network, which we wouldnt connect to the internet and run tell Dropbox to run on that network as it has LAN sharing, i know this wouldnt share the data to external devices, unitl we connected to an internet connection, but for our purposes this is fine.

While we want to have a second network we still need our main one to connect to the internet so is there a way we can get our computers all Mac OSX to connect to two wifi networks simultaneously and tell it to use one for Dropbox only and the other for everything else.

Comment: Is there any good reason this (or the actual network to the world) needs to be wireless? You'll have to install a second wireless network interface to connect to two wireless networks at once - which is certainly do-able with things like USB-WiFi adapters - but if the computers are not actually moving around, you'll get much better network if you simply run wires and have gigabit, rather than using WiFi - you can very likely run both your file updates and your outside networking on the same wires and still be faster than you are with WiFi.

Comment: Most of the machines are laptops and are taken home at night, taken to meets or moved around the office, its also quite a pain to run have lots of cables running around, as we dont have a raised floor.

Comment: If you have a dropped ceiling you don't need a raised floor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with using multi-homed computers, either wired or wireless. You will just need to configure the [`route`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/route.8.html) for the second network.

However if you use using wireless B/G (2.4GHz bands) then you will need to make sure that there are no overlapping channels.

For more information on wireless channels see [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11). Specifically the following graphs:

[image: Wireless channels 2.4GHz]

If you are using the 5GHz band then this should not be a problem since it has many more bands.

Not asked, but why not use a file-server to host your 100 mbit files?