# Three Netgear WiFi Access points, connected with wires, in the same network

Tags: wireless-networking

I have 3-story house, and when I tried to put my wifi router couldn’t cover some upper level rooms and the remote corner of my router’s level with decent quality signal. 
I'd like to have a single network inside though, not several different ones, as it easies the stuff like sharing files and accessing other's computers without setting VPNs.
I am thinking maybe it would be an option to put an access point in each room, connect them all via ethernet cables to the router - but how could I then have the same network on all of them? Wouldn't it lead to some conflicts between different points in the network infrastructure?
I would great appreciate it if you advised me a solution in a situation like this.

Comment: SuperUser Posts; [several wifi access points](https://superuser.com/questions/699794/) , [How to extend internet coverage on this apartment?](https://superuser.com/questions/1074270/how-to-extend-internet-coverage-on-this-apt?rq=1) , [Second wifi network connected to main router](https://superuser.com/questions/1170350/second-wifi-network-connected-to-main-router) , [Over Lapping Channels](https://superuser.com/a/663169/900431)

Answer (score 0):

If you can arrange to connect the access points to the main router by Ethernet (you suggest you can), that is the very best way.

You can connect them all on the same subnet.

Start with first access point, connect it by Ethernet to a LAN port on the main router. See if you can connect the Access Point by Static IP to the main network. Then turn DHCP OFF on the Access Point. Now it is one the main network IP Subnet. Test that this works.

Repeat the same way for the second and third routers, different Static IP addresses.

If the Access Points do not have these settings, then they should set up on the main network automatically on the same subnet. You may need controller software on a PC to manage the access points if this is the case.

Set up wireless. Depending on the access point design, you should be able to use the same SSID for each connection.

I use a Ubiquiti Access Point for the same thing and it works fine.